# Apache: No matching DirectoryIndex

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, directory, httpd.conf

I'm newbie in apache, i have the following directory structure:

```
html
|-- moodle
    |-- singapur
        |-- app
        |-- public
           |-- js
           |-- css
           |-- img
           |-- index.php
```

I need redirect from `www.mywebpage.com/singapur` to `www.mywebpage.com/singapur/public`

the `.htaccess` located in the folder `singapur` is:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /singapur/
    RewriteRule .* public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the `.htaccess` located in the folder `public` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /singapur/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The file `moodle.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName webpageexample.cl
        ServerAlias www.webpageexample.cl
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
        <Directory /var/www/html/moodle/>
             Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             allow from all
             Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But, when i try access to `webpageexample.cl/singapur` from web browser, i obtain the following

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /singapur/ on this server.
```

in apache log:

```
Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/moodle/singapur/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RedirectionMatch` directive to foce Apache to send the user someplace else.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.anotherserver.com$1
```

Click [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for more knowledge.